# Playstation Store Censorship

Tags: ps4, the-witcher-3, psn

Is there a way to know if a game is the censored version of the game? For example, I have a UAE account and want to buy the Witcher 3 digitally. The game is censored in the country, but not sure about the digital version.

Comment: How naive I am! I didn't even realize there were censored and non-censored versions. I wonder which version I am? (Steam purchased version for Windows in U.S.A.)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Yes.

Long Answer: Yes, because the country is governed by laws that dictate censorship and it is not dependent upon the medium on or by which the product is obtained.